# Fitting models with class probabilities with caret in R?

Tags: r, machine-learning, r-caret

I'm working on making some predictions with stacked ML algorithms in R, and I have successfully prepared the sub-models (see working code below:

```
trainSet <- read.csv("train.csv")
testSet <- read.csv("test.csv")

trainSet$Survived <- as.factor(trainSet$Survived)

algorithmList <- c('lda', 'rpart', 'glm', 'knn', 'svmRadial')

# create submodels
control <- trainControl(method="repeatedcv", number=10, repeats=3, savePredictions=TRUE, classProbs=TRUE)

set.seed(seed)
models <- caretList(Survived~ Pclass + Sex + Fare, data=trainSet, trControl=control, methodList=algorithmList)
results <- resamples(models)
summary(results)
dotplot(results)
```

but when I actually go to stack the sub-models:

```
# stack using glm
stackControl <- trainControl(method="repeatedcv", number=10, repeats=3, savePredictions=TRUE, classProbs=TRUE)
set.seed(seed)
stack.glm <- caretStack(models, method="glm", metric="Accuracy", trControl=stackControl)
print(stack.glm)
```

It gives me the error message:

```
Error in check_caretList_model_types(list_of_models) : 
  The following models were fit by caret::train with no class probabilities: lda, rpart, glm, knn, svmRadial.
Please re-fit them with trainControl(classProbs=TRUE)
```

But, as you can see, I believe I actually **did** fit them with classProbs=TRUE (see my 'control' variable) and don't understand why I'm getting this error message!  Any ideas?

Comment: Providing a reproducible example and the results of `sessionInfo` will help get your question answered.